# FPDF: Mergin 2 PDF files into 1 PDF with 1 page

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to merge 2 PDFs into 1 PDF with only one page. Every PDF has 1 page.

Thanks to this post 
http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/
I was able to make the first PDF the template. Only Problem now is how do I import the other and set it as content without getting a PDF with multiple pages as result.

I hope somebody can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An imported page doesn't mean that it results in a new page in your document until you write the code for this behaviour. Taking the example on the linked page you can import another documents page this way:

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pdf->setSourceFile("Fantastic-Speaker.pdf");
$tplIdxA = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pdf->setSourceFile("Another-Fantastic-Speaker.pdf");
$tplIdxB = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pdf->addPage();
// place the imported page of the first document:
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdxA, 10, 10, 90);
// place the imported page of the snd document:
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdxB, 100, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. only thing i changed was $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdxA, 10, 10, 200);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdxB, 10, 10, 200);